# How to install pygame on 64 bit python 3.4

Tags: python, pygame

I am looking to start programming using pygame however i cannot find a way to get a version for 64bit python 3.4. If anyone could help i would be grateful
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pygame
```

should work, but you'll probably have better luck with python 3.5 or 3.6; I was not able to pip install it for python 3.4

The wheels are available on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygame)

There is a [installation page](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) on the (new) pygame website.

Comment: Do i have to install a file first or can i just run the code?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: is there a download for the pygame module? or do i just run the code?

Comment: If you pip install it, nope, there is no other file to download first; the dependencies should be handled automatically.

Comment: i just installed 3.6 and when i use the pip function it returns invalid syntax

Comment: invalid syntax?? - is that a terminal message, or a python message?

Comment: i read online that its better to sue python 32 bit?

Comment: @skk10101 you have to enter `pip install pygame` in the command-line/terminal not in the Python shell. Which operating system do you use?

Comment: i'm using windows 10  64 bit and that is what i have done

Comment: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. is what is returned